# String in the small description Luma Theme

Tags: luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

I noticed this string in the small description. This "nessuno" string is seen only in Italian view while for other views it does not go out. How can I remove it? What is this string?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to search for your issue but i know a easy way to solve.
Go and activate the inline translation and translate that word with empty space.